# SO Synonym Request: [tag:script] and [tag:scripting]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

On StackOverflow [scripting](/questions/tagged/scripting) already has as [scripts](/questions/tagged/scripts) as a synonym.

We also have [script](/questions/tagged/script), and I propose that it be made a synonym of [scripting](/questions/tagged/scripting). I can't make this recommendation on SO because I don't have the required score in these tags. (I spend a fair bit of time replacing these generic tags with more specific ones on the questions in my interest area... if I didn't, I'd have the rep! Catch-22...)

All three are about scripts in general, with no specific technology indicated. There are more specific script tags, e.g. [bash-script](/questions/tagged/bash-script) and [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), which would be unaffected.

Comment: Why do we even need tags for generic scripting?

Comment: @Wooble - Hear, Hear! A quick count on one page of [script] shows 64% of askers have <10 rep, 92% <500... implying that the questions in these generic tags are too easily settled upon by new users.

Comment: By the way, questions tagged [script] may be specific to html tag <script>. I think they should be somehow retagged

Comment: @RiaD - The tag wiki says "A small program written to be read and executed by a command interpreter or another scripting language.", no mention of html... so, yes, if there are questions about html `<script>`, they need to be retagged - but they are already tagged wrong, so that has no bearing on making this a synonym. (... and most with [html][script] seem to be about [php] anyway, so maybe they just need [script] removed?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really would seem to me that both tags could be cleaned up and burninated.

A scripting tag seems about a useful as a Programming tag. A cleanup effort would involve determining what language the script in question is referring to and replace the script/scripting tag with that language's tag.

Comment: You read my mind - I've been migrating [google][script] and [google][scripting] to [google-apps-script] for weeks. My observation is that in most cases, the generic tag is already redundant - e.g. [python][script] - so in the vast majority of cases, it's enough to just remove the generic (useless) tag.

Comment: Is there some way to automate the process of removing or blending tags? I've been doing this one-at-a-time, focusing on a set of redundancies at a time, and while I've eliminated many, it's just too painful.